# Buttons positioning in HTML form

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<tr>   
                <td>
                    <div class="fileinputs">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="fileinputs">
                            <input type="file" class="file" name="uploadedfile" />
                        <div class="fakefile">
                                <img src="uf_btt.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fileinputs">   
                    <input type="reset" class="reset" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="fileinputs">
                    <input type="button" class="print" onclick="window.print()" />
                    </div>
                </td>   
            </tr>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
div.fileinputs {
    position: relative;
}

div.fakefile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

input.file {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity:0 ;
    filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

As a result, the buttons are positioned vertically, one below the other. In IE only "Upload File" button is seen.
I need all the buttons to be positioned horizontally, one next to the other, and look consistent in all browsers.
How do I obtain that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you might want to learn about [CSS float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp). alternatively use SPAN instead of DIVS, or DIVs with 'display:inline' style

Comment: Thank you!
I used 'float:left', and it worked.
The only problem remains there - IE still only displays one button instead of four - "Upload file".